# Error sending email: Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified. craft cms

Tags: error-message, configuration, error-handling

I'm testing my email and I'm seeing the following error in the web logs:

> "Error sending email: Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified. craft cms"

Does anyone know what that means?

In my local environment I am not seeing what exactly causes this error.
I've tried following this article on Craft but it seems like this is not relevant to the error I am receiving?

https://craftcms.com/guides/troubleshooting-email-errors

Also, I don't see the file structure they mention on this article, I found the error log on `storage/logs/web.txt`.

I've tried also changing my email to SMTP with Outlook credentials to no avail.

The images show the directory structure I'm seeing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvDex.png

Answer (score 1):

> Error sending email: Process could not be started

That error means that you've got `sendmail` selected as the mail driver for Craft under Settings->Email in the Control Panel, but the sendmail executable is either not installed or configured properly on your server.

> Also, I don't see the file structure they mention on this article, I found the error log on storage/logs/web.txt.

That's correct... the article was written for Craft 2 and you're using Craft 3. The log paths changed a bit between the two versions.

> I've tried also changing my email to SMTP with Outlook credentials to no avail.

I'm guessing you got a different error then?  I'd suggest setting up Craft with a transactional email provider like https://postmarkapp.com/ or https://sendgrid.com/.

There are Craft plugins for each (https://plugins.craftcms.com/sendgrid and https://plugins.craftcms.com/postmark), they'll be more reliable than sendmail and easier to setup than SMTP.